# laravel Invalid JSON was returned from the route. Perhaps an exception was thrown?

Tags: php, json, unit-testing, testing, laravel-5.1

This is my test for store function

```
/** @test */
public function storeTest()
{
    $this->be($this->user);
    $response = $this->json('POST', '/client/ocp/profile/247/route-', [
        'name'       => 'Test store',
        'speed'      => 4.5,
        'created_by' => $this->user->id,
        'client_id'  => '262',

    ]);
    $response
        ->seeStatusCode(302)
        ->seeJson(['status' => 'OK']);

}
```

when i run it i got this error

```
Invalid JSON was returned from the route. Perhaps an exception was thrown?
```

i try to add this header to solve a problem
['X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest']
but it not solving

how i can solve this?

Comment: Well you are building invalid json

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: Can you show the `Route` or controller method that is actually returning the json?

Comment: This is the controller 
https://repl.it/ExQi/79

Comment: and this is the route
|        |POST                           | client/{clientAlias}/page/{pageId}/routData                        | client.{clientAlias}.profile.{pageId}.routData.store   | App\Http\Controllers\RouteDataController@store                               |                             |

Comment: I put my controller method and route